# Organizing or Color Coding Project & Folders in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I am looking for an extension to Visual Studio 2010 which would allow for better organization of the solution, projects, folders and files.  I would really like to be able to color code specific project and folders.  For example, my team is working on and ASP.Net webforms site and integrating ASP.Net MVC.  I would love to be able to color code the MVC folders as that is where I do the majority of my work, or otherwise call them out and/or hide/grey-out other folders.

Another nice-to-have would be a set of bookmark icons or favorite files / folders.  For example, in MVC land I often find myself working on a set of files at one time: a view, one or more partial views, a controller, model files, services, utility classes, and scripts.  I might have 10 files associated with a particular "page" and it would be nice to be able to group this together into some sort of multi-tab favorite.

Are there any extension out there that do this, and if so what are your experiences with them?

Comment: This is unfortunately still not possible. Regarding color coded projects there is a related developer community suggestion which can be found here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Being-able-to-change-color-of-a-project/1565503

Answer (score 4):

I haven't seen anything out there that gives you exactly what you're looking for.  However, if you're not familiar with the Visual Studio [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef?SRC=Home), you might want to check them out.

Among other features, they provide the ability to color-code the document tabs based on project and/or regular expressions (applied against the filename).  Depending on how your model, view, and controller classes are named, you may be able to apply a set of regular expressions to the filenames to come up with a tab coloring scheme (this add-in won't help you with the solution explorer, however).

Just thought I'd point that out in case you're not aware of this set of tools.

Hope this helps.